# Iterating through a list containing structs known at compile-time

Tags: oop, rust

I'm unable to run the following code because I'm trying to index the struct instead of using a hard-coded name. Other languages do this, but Rust doesn't seem to given its nature of not being object oriented. The official book doesn't even have a good way of doing the following:

```
struct Address {
    number: u32,
    city: String,
}

fn print_an_address()  {

    let Address[0] = {
        number: 1,
        city: "New York",
    }
    println!("{}", address[0]);

}
```

Comment: The syntax in your example isn't valid and there's no lists in your code, so it's not clear 
to be exactly what you're trying to do? Do you have equivalent piece of code for what you're trying to do from one of the other languages you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust does have this, you're just not using the right syntax.  For example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Address {
    number: u32,
    city: String,
}

fn print_an_address() {
    let address = [
        Address {
            number: 1,
            city: "New York".to_string(),
        }
    ];
    
    println!("{:?}", address[0]);
}
```

The local variable `address` has the array type `[Address; 1]` here.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=329c2a6757c1ca26eef36f1996f53923))

You can easily add more elements.  Here we add a second element and iterate over the array instead of fetching a specific index.  The type of `address` here has changed to `[Address; 2]`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Address {
    number: u32,
    city: String,
}

fn print_addresses() {
    let address = [
        Address {
            number: 1,
            city: "New York".to_string(),
        },
        Address {
            number: 2,
            city: "Boston".to_string(),
        },
    ];
    
    for i in address {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0180208ebe1ca6c66f1f4208de35f445))

Comment: Isnt it better to use an vector in case he wants to add more items to it?

Comment: @bill.gates No. A vector requires a heap allocation to store the elements, and we don't have enough information to determine that's warranted here. If that is desired, it's just a matter of adding `vec!`, but otherwise an array makes more sense.